# beautifulsoup - how to convert back from soup to html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to convert parse and edit an html. This works perfectly, but, when converting the soup object back to html with prettify(formatter="html"), it adds a lot of spaces and newlines that were not in the original html

What can i do to keep the original formatting?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the original formatting? Yeah it formats it but in a way so that it doesn't affect the webpage at all, just makes the html a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

*Cause you create `BeautifulSoup` object from a string a general approach would be to convert it back in this way. To get a more specific answer, please improve question and add details to clarify.*

String to `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
```

`BeautifulSoup` object to string:

```
str(soup)
```

Comment: What i want is to read a html, edit this (i find this easy with beautifulsoup) and then, upload the html i have modified